# What are the pros & cons of the different C++ clocks for logging time stamps?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

When printing my logs, I want each message to have a time stamp, measuring time since start of the program. Preferably in nanoseconds, though milliseconds are fine as well:

```
(  110 ns) Some log line 
( 1220 ns) Another log line 
( 2431 ns) Now for some computation...
(10357 ns) Error!
```

To my understanding, there three different clocks in the C++ chrono library and two more C-style clocks:

- std::chrono::high_resolution_clock
- std::chrono::system_clock
- std::chrono::steady_clock
- std::time
- std::clock

What are the pros and cons for each those for the task described above?

Comment: `What are the pros and cons` What research did you do? Do you know at least what is a monotonic clock and which one is and isn't monotonic? You did not specify exact requirement for the timestamp in your messages, this makes an answer to your question opinion based - one may prefer non-monotonic clock to represent wall time of the message readable to user, one may not. `Preferably in nanoseconds` So do you think `std::time` is ok? What do you think `std::clock` represents? Should CPU time used by your process be used as timestamp in messages? On the end, it depends on the messages..

Comment: Try this article from Rainer Grimm: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-three-clocks

Comment: Changed title because there is no language "C/C++" and OP has language tag of only C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`system_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system) is a clock that keeps time with UTC (excluding leap seconds).  Every once in a while (maybe several times a day), it gets adjusted by small amounts, to keep it aligned with the correct time.  This is often done with a network service such as NTP.  These adjustments are typically on the order of microseconds, but can be either forward or backwards in time.  It is actually possible (though not likely nor common) for timestamps from this clock to go backwards by tiny amounts.  Unless abused by an administrator, `system_clock` does not jump by gross amounts, say due to daylight saving, or changing the computer's local time zone, since it always tracks UTC.

[`steady_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.steady) is like a stopwatch.  It has no relationship to any time standard.  It just keeps ticking.  It may not keep perfect time (no clock does really).  But it will never be adjusted, especially not backwards.  It is great for timing short bits of code.  But since it never gets adjusted, it may drift over time with respect to `system_clock` which is adjusted to keep in sync with UTC.

This boils down to the fact that `steady_clock` is best for timing short durations.  It also typically has nanosecond resolution, though that is not required.  And `system_clock` is best for timing "long" times where "long" is very fuzzy.  But certainly hours or days qualifies as "long", and durations under a second don't.  And if you need to relate a timestamp to a human readable time such as a date/time on the civil calendar, `system_clock` is the only choice.

[`high_resolution_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.hires) is allowed to be a type alias for either `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, and in practice always is.  But some platforms alias to `steady_clock` and some to `system_clock`.  So imho, it is best to just directly choose `steady_clock` or `system_clock` so that you know what you're getting.

Though not specified, [`std::time`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ctime.syn) is typically restricted to a resolution of a second.  So it is completely unusable for situations that require subsecond precision.  Otherwise `std::time` tracks UTC (excluding leap seconds), just like `system_clock`.

[`std::clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ctime.syn) tracks processor time, as opposed to physical time.  That is, when your thread is not busy doing something, and the OS has parked it, measurements of `std::clock` will not reflect time increasing during that down time.  This can be really useful if that is what you need to measure.  And it can be very surprising if you use it without realizing that processor time is what you're measuring.

### And new for C++20

C++20 adds four more clocks to the `<chrono>` library:

[`utc_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc) is just like `system_clock`, except that it counts leap seconds.  This is mainly useful when you need to subtract two `time_point`s across a leap second insertion point, and you absolutely need to count that inserted leap second (or a fraction thereof).

[`tai_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.tai) measures seconds since 1958-01-01 00:00:00 and is offset 10s ahead of UTC at this date.  It doesn't have leap seconds, but every time a leap second is inserted into UTC, the calendrical representation of TAI and UTC diverge by another second.

[`gps_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.gps) models the GPS time system.  It measures seconds since the first Sunday of January, 1980 00:00:00 UTC.  Like TAI, every time a leap second is inserted into UTC, the calendrical representation of GPS and UTC diverge by another second.  Because of the similarity in the way that GPS and TAI handle UTC leap seconds, the calendrical representation of GPS is always behind that of TAI by 19 seconds.

[`file_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.file) is the clock used by the `filesystem` library, and is what produces the `chrono::time_point` aliased by `std::filesystem::file_time_type`.

One can use a new named cast in C++20 called `clock_cast` to convert among the `time_point`s of `system_clock`, `utc_clock`, `tai_clock`, `gps_clock` and `file_clock`.  For example:

```
auto tp = clock_cast<system_clock>(last_write_time("some_path/some_file.xxx"));
```

The type of `tp` is a `system_clock`-based `time_point` with the same `duration` type (precision) as `file_time_type`.

Comment: Quite interestingly, some resources such as the guys at `cppreference.com` believe that `high_resolution_clock` is to unspecified and `its use should be avoided`.

Comment: @shuhalo Yes.  I gave them that advice.  And that is consistent with what I write above.

Comment: So is there any reason to prefer system_clock over utc_clock assuming your compilers/libraries support the latter? Seems like I would just want to use utc_clock by default, since that's how most software passes around datetime values anyway...

Comment: Yes. `system_clock` is what is used by mainstream OS's: Windows, Linux, macOS, etc.  This is also known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  This measure has the advantage of efficient conversion to and from date/time fields:  `{y, m, d, H, M, S}`.  Computing with leap seconds adds complexity and inefficiency.  And no consumer product is going to give subsecond accuracy during a leap second insertion.  Almost all computers use Unix Time (`system_clock`) for a reason. Only use `utc_clock` when you know that your computation must take leap seconds into account.