# C++ chrono convert string with microseconds precision to chrono object

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

I'm parsing SVN logs and they contain date/time with this format `2023-09-23T23:08:30.383815Z`.

I need to convert this to a time object (supposed `std::chrono::steady_clock` was the good format). However, all code I could find to do so uses std::tm that does not have microseconds precision:

```
std::tm t = {};
std::istringstream ss("2023-09-23T23:12:34Z");
ss >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

if (ss.fail())
    std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
else
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%c") << '\n';
```

What function should be used to convert such a string to any `std::chrono` object preserving microseconds information?

Note: I'm not using C++20, so [Convert a string with micro second precision to a chrono time_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881925/convert-a-string-with-micro-second-precision-to-a-chrono-time-point) and [Can std::chrono::from_stream convert string to time_point with microseconds accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556057/can-stdchronofrom-stream-convert-string-to-time-point-with-microseconds-accu) are not duplicates.

Comment: [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) about steady_clock: *This clock is not related to wall clock time.* It is probably not suitable for your needs.

Comment: @j6t: Yes probably a time_point would be better, but even so I could not find how to correctly parse  the string

Comment: As I understand it, parsing a date needs a calendar. Calendar facilities are not available in pre-C++20 editions, and conversion of a parsed `std::tm` to `system_clock::time_point`s manually is tedious and error prone. You can use Howard Hinnant's date library. It does all the nitty-gritty details for you.

Comment: I'd like a solution using only C++, I can't believe this is not doable. Or I'll probably end up using a boost library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++17 you either need to parse this yourself, at least the microseconds part.  Or you can use my [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  This library is where the C++20 chrono parts come from, and so it is very easy to port this code to C++20 when that time comes for you.

However, no matter what code you use (mine, yours, or someone else's), you will need to parse into a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, not `steady_clock`.  [See this for more information about the different clocks.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084510/576911)

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;


    sys_time<microseconds> t;
    std::istringstream ss("2023-09-23T23:08:30.383815Z");
    ss >> parse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", t);

    if (ss.fail())
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    else
        cout << t << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2023-09-23 23:08:30.383815
```

You could also use this equivalent, shorter parse format: `"%FT%TZ"`.  `%F` is a shortcut for `%Y-%m-%d`, and `%T` is a shortcut for `%H:%M:%S`.

To port this to C++20, drop `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.

Comment: OK thanks, now I understood why I spent hours trying to do this with no success...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to boost library:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

bool strToTime( const std::string& timeStr, boost::posix_time::ptime& time )
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime converter;
    boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *tif = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet;
    tif->set_iso_extended_format();
    std::istringstream iss(timeStr);
    iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), tif));
    iss >> time;

    return !iss.fail();
}

int
main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime time;

    if (!strToTime("2023-09-23T23:08:30.383815Z",time))
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    else
        std::cout << time << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
2023-Sep-23 23:08:30.383815
```