C++: Is it possible to get the realtime (independent of current CPU frequency and load) as unix timestamp with nanosecond precision?
Currently I calculate it as 100-nanoseconds intervals (windows FileTime) using current CPU frequency and __rdtsc() function:
typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds> TimePoint;

void Services::GetRealTime(int64_t* RTime) // Time in 100-nanosecond intervals
{
    *RTime = RealTime + (INT64)((__rdtsc() - rdtscPrevVal) * (1.0 / CPUFrequency));
}

void    Services::GetRealTime(TimePoint& timePoint) 
{
    int64_t realTime;
    GetRealTime(&realTime);
    timePoint = TimePoint(std::chrono::duration_cast<TimePoint::duration>(std::chrono::nanoseconds(realTime * 100)));
}

But I'm sure that c++ has more reliable, crossplatform and precise way to do it. How can I do it? Will the std::chrono::steady_clock::now() do the job?
I need to precise measure of events time in nanoseconds independent of current CPU loading and throttling.

Some platforms do not provide nanosecond precision.  Whatever the answer is will be constrained by what the platform provides.  (For example, one platform I worked on only had a RTC that provided 1/60th of a second precision in the US, or 1/50th of a second precision in Europe.)

C++ is not designed to be cross-platform (works in same manner everywhere) but platform-dependent (does everywhere something that is heavily platform-defined). Most RTC chips use 32.768 kHz crystal oscillators, that is about 30518 nano-second cycle. C++ cant conjure out what hardware does not provide.

So, is it impossible to measure nanoseconds on PC using c++?

@Eljay Can I use some libraries?

@Eljay Ok, I don't need full crossplatform support. I need only linux (and maybe windows but is is not necessary)

Where do you need your accurate time measurement for? Note that neither Linux nor Windows are real-time-os's so you can't control when you ask for the time

Yep. Smells XY problem. What is supposedly the nature of such events that have few nanoseconds between those? For example human hears up to about 20 kHz sounds, that means 50 000 nano-seconds/cycle.

@PepijnKramer "Where do you need your accurate time measurement for?" calculation phase difference between different waves. I need as precise time as possible for this to increase accuracy

Now, here are a few thoughts on clocks and stuff.
First of all, C++ gives you std::chrono::high_resolution_clock. It does not give you any guarantees about the actual resolution, though. If you want guarantees, you have to go to the OS level and carefully read their documentation on actual resolution vs. the values returned -- just because something returns "nanoseconds" doesn't mean it's measuring nanoseconds.
Now, "unix timestamp" doesn't actually exist, so I'll just assume you're talking about something like the time_t, except scaled up to nanoseconds. From a C++ perspective, this means converting a time point to std::chrono::system_clock -- which, unfortunately, might not have nanosecond precision. Also, last time I tried using std::chrono::clock_cast, my compiler did not yet have that.
Assuming that you have a working std::chrono::clock_cast, you could still try to do something like this: cut the nanoseconds from the high_resolution_clock timepoint, convert to system_clock, take the time_t, multiply by 1000000000, and add the nanoseconds. Still, that's "if" you have clock_cast, and "if" you get nanoseconds to start with...
At the end of the day, I would likely stick with OS-calls if I definitely want nanoseconds. As long as we don't get something like std::chrono::nano_clock defined as "as close to a nanosecond-clock as the system can muster", the available clocks just don't cut it.
If you don't have a clock_cast, conversions are still possible, although a bit hackish and they will likely loose more accuracy than clock_cast would.
So, really, if you want "event times", why does it have to be "real time"? For log output or something like that, loss of accuracy wouldn't be much of an issue, IMHO, and the event data could just have whatever timestamps you get before converting them to "nanosecond time_t`.
However, as an easy workaround to avoid OS calls, you could just typedef your own "MyClock", and examine what the systems you use actually offer. As an example, on Windows, C++20 std::chrono::file_clock is likely the same 100ns-resolution clock that you currently use, except wrapped into a C++ clock. Someone on a different platform might typedef MyClock to a different clock, so a few #ifdef could provide reasonable portability.
Heck, if you're targeting Windows only, file_clock even has built-in conversions to either system_clock or utc_clock, so that might help you on the way to a time_t (again, I haven't examined what utc_clock and or cannot offer you).
Also, while I haven't examined this option myself, it might be possible to examine the resolution of the various clock types at compiletime, and basically have the compiler work out the MyClock for you by looking at things like high_resolution_clock and file_clock and choosing the better one for you. With that, you loose the conversion that file_clock offers, though.
This will still limit you to clocks that the C++ implementation actually offers, though. The operating system might have something that you might prefer, but the C++ implementation might not wrap that one...

"cut the nanoseconds from the high_resolution_clock timepoint, convert to system_clock, take the time_t, multiply by 1000000000"
It doesn't look like precise time measurement. I need to measure time of events that could happen very often, few nanoseconds between them. Maybe, linux has some library that could do it?

Fwiw, here is a survey of the different clocks available in portable C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084510/576911.  I say "portable" as this survey does not include clocks specified by the OS API, but only those specified by the C++ spec, and those imported from the C spec.
